# Is there anyway to quickly get my Analytics profile ids?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I can get profile ids with Management API but it's a bit complicated. Is there any easy to get all my profile ids?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware that you can pass the string `~all` for the `accountId` and `webPropertyID` parameters when listing profiles using the Management API? So all you need to get a list of all profiles is:

**HTTP**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles
```

**Java**

```
Profiles profiles = analytics.management.profiles.list("~all", "~all").execute();
```

Reading the ids from the returned profiles is also trivial.

How can you expect there to be an easier way?

Comment: OMG, it works! Great! But there is another question, why sometimes I can get the `defaultProfileId` but sometimes not? I need that id to do further queries and I don't want to use `gapi.client.analytics.management.profiles.list` to query the details for each web property. (I am afraid very few people would add more profiles in one web property)

Comment: Please open a new question.

Comment: Why don't they document stuff like that.  Ok its not bad but it would be nice if it returned all the info. Accounts, WebProperties, vies(profiles) everything in one call.  But still this should get my what was one a load of requests down to just 3.  Wish I could give you more then +1 on this.

Comment: @DaImTo This feature [is documented in the API reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/list).